# Laravel eloquent relationship has many through doesn't work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm making a sort of like reddit website.

I have users, threadKarmas, commentKarmas table/model.

I want to retrieve the user along with the number of his karmas through the threads and comment he has created.

```
$user = UserView::with([
            'threadKarmaPoints',
            'commentKarmaPoints'
            ])
            ->where('username', $username)
            ->firstOrFail();
```

User Relationships:

```
public function threadKarmaPoints() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\ThreadKarmaView',
        'App\Models\ThreadView',
        'userId',
        'threadId',
        'userId',
        'threadId'
        )->count();
}

    public function commentKarmaPoints() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\CommentKarmaView',
        'App\Models\CommentView',
        'userId',
        'commentId',
        'userId',
        'commentId'
        )->count();
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Views\UserView', 'userId');
}
```

No inverse relationship yet. I don't know how I will create it but for now, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `->count();` from both relationship definitions and use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
UserView::withCount(['threadKarmaPoints', 'commentKarmaPoints'])
    ->where('username', $username)
    ->firstOrFail();
```

If you also need to actually load related data, add `->with(['threadKarmaPoints', 'commentKarmaPoints'])` to the query.

Comment: It returns empty array.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer it can't return an empty array. It will return an object with `threadKarmaPoints_count` and `commentKarmaPoints_count` properties or an exception will be thrown if there is no `UserView` where `username = $username`

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer it's not related to the query. If you're using AJAX call of something, you can put `info($user);` right after the query and look at the result in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file.

Comment: I get empty array. I tried removing both relationship then tried adding a different relationship  ->with('profile') and it returned a data.